# Powershell - I am unable to match a string in an if statement even if I use -contains instead of -eq

Tags: powershell, csv, join, split

I have a .csv file that I need to change a field based on the value of another field.
The important part of the data is:
"08-01-2023 09:00:00","08-02-2023 09:00:00",**"937600","Sonat Measurement"**,...

I want to change the "Sonat Measurement" field value in each row based on what we have in the previous field.

```
    $data = Get-Content $AFw
    Foreach ($row in $data){
        $values = $row -split ','
        Write-Host $values[2]
        Write-host $values[3]
        if ($values[2] -contains 937600){
            $values[3] = "SNG TRUMBOWER NASSAU"
            } elseif ($values[2] -contains 937700){
                $values[3] = "SNG NORMANDY  DUVALL"
                } elseif ($values[2] -contains 960530){
                    $values[3] = "SNG JACKSONVILLE NASSAU"
                    } elseif ($values[2] -contains 960590){
                        $values[3] = "SNG BAKER NASSAU"
                        } elseif ($values[2] -contains 96108){
                            $values[3] = "WILDWOOD"
                            } elseif ($values[2] -contains 10){
                                $values[3] = "DRAINFIELD"
                                }

        $newRow = $values -join ','
        $data = $data -replace [regex]::Escape($row), $newRow

    }
```

I have tried -eq, -contains, all versions of quotes "", '' without quotes, etc. I havent even gotten to the join portion of the code.
Write-host $value[2] prints out "937600"
Write-host $value[3] prints out "Sonat Measurement"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex and replace all the data. May not be the most efficient way, but hope this helps.

```
# Create matching pattern
$findPattern = '"{pattern}","Sonat Measurement"'

# Create replacement pattern
$replacePattern = '"{pattern}","{newMeasurement}"'

# Create an array of replacements. if you need a bunch, get them from a file. This has two hardcoded elements.
$replacements = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        value = "937600"
        newMeasurement = "SNG TRUMBOWER NASSAU"
    },
    [PSCustomObject]@{
    value = "937700"
    newMeasurement = "SNG NORMANDY DUVALL"
    }
)

# Read the data from the file.
$data = Get-Content "C:\Projects\PSTests\data.txt" -Raw

# loop through the replacement array replacing all values in the file.
foreach($replacement in $replacements)
{
    $fpattern = $findPattern.Replace("{pattern}",$replacement.value)
    $rpattern = $replacePattern.`
        Replace("{pattern}",$replacement.value). `
        Replace("{newMeasurement}",$replacement.newMeasurement)  
    $data = $data -Replace $fpattern, $rpattern
}

# put data out to a file     
$data | out-file -FilePath "C:\Projects\PSTests\newdata.txt"
```

Comment: Both of these solutions would have worked but I used the regex one because I didnt have headers in the file at this point in processing. Thanks to everyone for their efforts. SB

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: improved the code. Thanks @mkelement0

You are mistaking... many things.

First, if it's a CSV just use `Import-Csv`. Makes managing everything much easier.

Second, more directly related to your problem... `-contains` does NOT do what you think it does.

To put it simple: `$Collection -contains $Element`
To check if a string contains a specific substring, you need to use `-like` or `-match`(this one uses regular expressions)

Third: use `Switch()`, by Dende!

```
# you can replace the names of the headers with whatever you want of course
$data = Import-Csv -Path $AFw -Delimiter ',' -Header FirstHeader, SecondHeader, ThirdHeader, FourthHeader #, etc etc.

$data.Foreach({
        Write-Host $_.FirstHeader
        Write-Host $_.SecondHeader

        # NOTE WELL:
        # this presume an exact string comparison.
        # to check for substrings: for use Switch -Regex () or Switch -Wildcard () with relative patterns
        switch ($_.ThirdHeader) {
            '937600' {
                $_.FourthHeader = 'SNG TRUMBOWER NASSAU' 
                break
            }
            '937700' {
                $_.FourthHeader = 'SNG NORMANDY  DUVALL' 
                break
            }
            '960530' {
                $_.FourthHeader = 'SNG JACKSONVILLE NASSAU' 
                break
            }
            '960590' {
                $_.FourthHeader = 'SNG BAKER NASSAU' 
                break
            }
            '96108' {
                $_.FourthHeader = 'WILDWOOD'
                break
            }
            '10' {
                $_.FourthHeader = 'DRAINFIELD' 
                break
            }
            Default {
                <# do nothing, I guess #> 
            }
        }

    })

# $data now contains the modified values
```

Comment: The ```switch``` could be simplified even further to a hashtable of key-value pairs of regex pattern and fourth-header values, and then just iterate over the keys - ```if( $_.ThirdHeader -like $kvp.Key ) { return $kvp.Value }```…